# Calculations with .tif images using matplotlib or rasterio

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff

How can I do processing with .tif images in Python?

For example suppose I have "Red_channel.tif" and "Blue_channel.tif" and I want to do the calculation (and produce a new .tif) like this:

```
"output.tif" = ("Red_channel.tif" + (("Blue_channel.tif")^3) + 4 + sqrt("Red_channel.tif"))
```

Comment: What GIS software are you using?  What have you tried?

Comment: I am asking about python code....

Comment: We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. This question now has a matplotlib/rasterio answer so if it's another Python library that you wish to ask about then please do that in a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If georeferencing is not important to you, you can simply do it with matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

red = plt.imread('path/to/Red_channel.tif')
blue = plt.imread('path/to/Blue_channel.tif')

result = red + blue**3 + 4 + red**0.5

plt.imsave('path/to/Output.tif', result)
```

If you want to maintain the georeferencing you should use rasterio instead.

```
import rasterio
with rasterio.open('path/to/Red_channel.tif') as f:
    red = f.read()
    profile = f.profile

with rasterio.open('path/to/Blue_channel.tif') as f:
    blue = f.read()

result = red + blue**3 + 4 + red**0.5

with rasterio.open('path/to/Output.tif', 'w', **profile) as dst:
    dst.write(result)
```

Comment: Parsa you are amazing!!!