# How can I get the channels of a .tiff UAV image and maintain the georeference

Tags: python, raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

So, the idea is that I have a .tif UAV image. I need to get R,G,B,A channels into 4 separate .tif files by maintaining the georeferencing. So, for instance: Red.tif, Green.tif, Blue.tif and Alpha.tif. I am using this approach:

```
(red, green, blue, alpha) = np.transpose(img, axes = (2,0,1))
```

Next, I want to do some calculations with the channels. For instance:

```
result = ((red**2)+(blue**2))/(blue)
```

I use this code in order to make the result.tif...

```
import rasterio
with rasterio.open('path/to/Red_channel.tif') as f:
    red = f.read()
    profile = f.profile

with rasterio.open('path/to/Blue_channel.tif') as f:
    blue = f.read()

result = ((red**2)+(blue**2))/(blue) 

with rasterio.open('path/to/Output.tif', 'w', **profile) as dst:
    dst.write(result)
```

(source: [Calculations with .tif images using matplotlib or rasterio](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/407821/calculations-with-tif-images-using-matplotlib-or-rasterio))

Now, the problem is that when I try to use the `Output.tif` with gdalinfo to see the real coordinates, it does **not** show real coordinates, it shows **pixel** coordinates for each corner!! Any idea what is wrong and how I fix this?

**Update**:
I store each of the bands after:

```
(red, green, blue, alpha) = np.transpose(f, axes = (2,0,1))
```

like this:

```
with rasterio.open('path/to/Green.tif', 'w', **profile) as dst:
    dst.write(green)
```

and I have set:

```
profile["count"] = 4
```

This is the error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 126, in bands
    (red, green, blue, alpha) = np.transpose(f, axes = (2,0,1))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in transpose
  File "/home/UbuntuUser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 653, in transpose
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'transpose', axes)
  File "/home/UbuntuUser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 55, in _wrapfunc
    return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
  File "/home/UbuntuUser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 44, in _wrapit
    result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
ValueError: axes don't match array
```

Comment: I have no experience using rasterio whatsoever, but my guess would be you only extract the values with your code and you would have to manually copy the origin and projection from the original image

Comment: ```f.read()``` reads the raster data to a numpy array. Hence, geospatial information is lost at this point.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://medium.com/@mommermiscience/dealing-with-geospatial-raster-data-in-python-with-rasterio-775e5ba0c9f5

Comment: If you have GDAL installed, you can use the code from this answer to get the geospatial information from the original file to your result https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/327239/150644

Comment: I try to read and write .tif with rasterio. But what is the equivalent of this command: `(red, green, blue, alpha) = np.transpose(img, axes = (2,0,1))` with rasterio??

Comment: I just tried to reproduce the issue but I am not sure where ```np.transpose``` comes in. I split a GTiff into R, G, and B and used your code to execute the calculation and save the output. QGIS displayed the resulting GTiff right above the original one, so I assume the georeferences are correct. Did you use ```np.transpose``` to generate the separate bands from a 4-band tiff?

Comment: Yes, I use `np.transpose` to generate the separate bands from a 4-band tiff.

Comment: Then my answer should work. You would just remove the ```profile = f.profile``` line from where you read the red band and add the other part of code I suggested. This will get the information from the original RGBa raster (instead fromthe red band which has lost its geo-information), which should be the information you need. Just change the number of bands as I pointed out.

Comment: I do not understand how do I split and  take the 4 channels from the initial image.tif ??

Comment: I extended the answer to make it more clear. You can still use ```(red, green, blue, alpha) = np.transpose(img, axes = (2,0,1))``` to split the image.

Comment: `R = os.path.join(wd, "xR.tif")` stores the Red.tif , right?

Comment: No, this is just in my example. This stores only the path to the red channel GTiff. ```R = os.path.join(wd, "xR.tif")``` creates the variable R with the value ```"C:\\Users\\Manuel\\Desktop\\test\\xR.tif"``` since I don't want to have to put the full paths everywhere. The function just pastes the ```wd``` string and the filename ```"xR.tif"``` and inserts the path separator ("\\" on Windows and "/" on Linux)

Comment: The part after **Complete:** is the part that matters. At the beginning of the answer I just described what I did and that it worked in my case (which means the problem occurred when the R, G, and B single bands were created or earlier). At the beginning I was not aware how you created the single channels from the multichannel. Now that I know that the geo-information was lost during the creation of the single R, G and B channels, I just suggested to obtain these information from the original image (the one that contains all 4 channels).

Comment: I just included a complete script that just reads in the original tiff file from your hard drive. The single channels are not saved as tiff here, since it is not required for the calculation. Saving them via additional code is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following with a GTiff image I split into R, G and B bands in QGIS:

```
wd = "C:\\Users\\Manuel\\Desktop\\test"
import rasterio, os
R = os.path.join(wd, "xR.tif")
B = os.path.join(wd, "xB.tif")
output = os.path.join(wd, "out.tif")

with rasterio.open(R) as f:
    red = f.read()
    profile = f.profile

with rasterio.open(B) as f:
    blue = f.read()

profile["dtype"] = "float64"
result = ((red**2)+(blue**2))/(blue) 

with rasterio.open(output, 'w', **profile) as dst:
    dst.write(result)
```

This produced the desired output. Note that my original image has RGB values in [0, 255] rather than in [0, 1]; hence, the `dtype` value of `profile` was `uint8` in the single-band GTiffs and the calculation resulted in floats, which is why I added the line `profile["dtype"] = "float64"` to have the correct `dtype` to write the output (maybe useful for some reader).

Since this part appears to work, I assume you lost the geoinformation when you split the original image into R, G, B, alpha bands? This should be no problem, since you could simply obtain the `profile` from the original GTiff instead of the red band. They should only differ in the number of bands, which can be fixed easily:

```
with rasterio.open(PATH_TO_ORIGINAL_GTIFF) as f:
    profile = f.profile
# set the number of bands in the extracted information to 1
profile["count"] = 1
```

**Complete:**

```
import rasterio
with rasterio.open('path/to/Original_4_channel.tif') as f:
    profile = f.profile
# set the number of bands to 1
profile["count"] = 1

# [INSERT WHAT EVER CODE YOU USED TO GET THE SINGLE R, G AND B CHANNELS HERE]
# e.g. load the image as img and run
# (red, green, blue, alpha) = np.transpose(img, axes = (2,0,1))

with rasterio.open('path/to/Red_channel.tif') as f:
    red = f.read()

with rasterio.open('path/to/Blue_channel.tif') as f:
    blue = f.read()

result = ((red**2)+(blue**2))/(blue) 

with rasterio.open('path/to/Output.tif', 'w', **profile) as dst:
    dst.write(result)
```

**Edit**

It was not part of your original question. Nevertheless, I included a way to get the separate raster channels before doing the calculations. This is a complete script that just takes the directory and file name of the original 4-channel GTiff image.

```
wd = "/path/to/your/GTiff_file"# just the folder without the filename
import rasterio, os
import numpy as np
img_path = os.path.join(wd, "INPUT_FILE_NAME.tif")# filename goes in here
out_path = os.path.join(wd, "OUTPUT_FILE_NAME.tif")

with rasterio.open(img_path) as f:
    profile = f.profile
    R = f.read(1)
    G = f.read(2)
    B = f.read(3)
    a = f.read(4)

profile["count"] = 1
profile["dtype"] = "float64"

result = ((R**2)+(B**2))/(B)
result = np.expand_dims(result, axis=0)

with rasterio.open(out_path, 'w', **profile) as dst:
    dst.write(result)
```

Comment: Please see my update on the initial post

Comment: ```ValueError: axes don't match array``` means the image currently stored under the variable name ```f``` has a number of dimensions that doesn't match what the function expects, given the parameters you set. Maybe you could provide the image somehow or show how you load it and what properties it has?

Comment: You are amazing!!!! The code works! One last question... in case I want to read the full path in the `img_path`, so the path + tif file, such as: `"/path/to/your/GTiff_file/INPUT_FILE_NAME.tif"` how I pass it to `os.path.join(..)`. I tried this command: `img_path = os.open("/path/to/your/GTiff_file/INPUT_FILE_NAME.tif", os.O_RDONLY)` but it does not work.... Any ideas?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to create ```img_path``` without using the ```wd``` variable? You could just replace ```wd``` with the directory path:
```img_path = os.path.join("/path/to/your/GTiff_file", "INPUT_FILE_NAME.tif")```
or you could set the variable directly as
```img_path = "/path/to/your/GTiff_file/INPUT_FILE_NAME.tif"```

Comment: The output file is unidentified with opencv, via which I am trying to open them....why? With the QGIS program, I open them without any problem....

Comment: Does this command: `(red, green, blue, alpha) = np.transpose(img, axes = (2,0,1))` affects the order that I get the color bands (channels). Does it reorder the channels?

Comment: The description of ```np.transpose``` says "Reverse or permute the axes of an array", so yes, you could probably change the order of bands. However, in the solution I gave there is no need for this function. Unfortunately, I just started learning Python 4 months ago and don't know every detail; I guess you will find better answers to such questions if you start a new question instead of commenting on this answer where few people will read it... I guess the people who know all the answers won't read this conversation